# asymmetric signal split at SMA Tee (wires of different lengths)

Tags: oscilloscope, phase-shift, split

I set up a circuit, as shown in the schematic below, to see firsthand how the signal paths of different lengths could lead to a phase difference.

I am using an SMA Tee and there is no reason to suspect that it's designed to split power unevenly.

What I noticed is that when cable 1 and cable 2 are the same length, no matter what the frequency of the signal is, the power split was perfectly even and there is no phase difference, which is perfectly reasonable.

What caught me off guard is how the power from the two output ports of the SMA Tee becomes uneven at some frequency value (on the order of MHz) if the cable lengths are different. At much lower frequency values, the power split appeared more or less even.  The cables are of the same material and company. The only difference is the lengths of the cables.

I now understand that because my oscilloscope does not have a high enough resolution to properly display microwave signal (GHz) it's going to be hard for me to see any noticeable phase lag from the cable length difference.  But, in the range of MHz, I would like to know what could explain the uneven power split at the SMA Tee.

[image]

Comment: Does the input impedance of the scope match the characteristic impedance of the cables?

Comment: have  you switched the oscilloscope connections to eliminate the possibility of the oscilloscope input being the culprit?

Comment: And are you using a simple Tee or a proper power splitter?

Comment: @DaveTweed  since both port 1 and port 2 have 50 ohm termination and the cables 1 and 2 both have 50 ohm characteristic impedance, I suppose with the SMA Tee putting them in parallel, it's no longer impedance matched.   Is this the correct way to understand that I am getting some interference and hence the amplitudes on port 1 and 2 are different?

Comment: No, not really. The only mismatch is right at the source (the tee), so there should not be standing waves on the cables to the scope. The tee itself sees two equal loads, so the power should divide evenly.

Comment: @jsotola Yes, I think the uneven power split is real because when I switched the oscilloscope connections, if it was port 1 that showed greater amplitude, it became port 2 that showed greater amplitude.

Comment: @DaveTweed thank you for your response. Everything is 50ohm, except for the SMA Tee.  I am not sure what is causing this uneven power split then. I switched the oscilloscope connections and confirmed that the uneven power split.

Comment: Did you also try swapping the cables *at the tee*? There might be some hidden asymmetry there.

Comment: @DaveTweed when the two cables are of the exact same length, the power split is always even. It's when I use different lengths that I see uneven power split at some frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

I presume this is because your scope inputs are not matched. If this is the case, then you'll get standing waves which will interfere and produce an amplitude difference. If you can't put the scope in 50 ohm mode or you're still getting reflections, insert attenuators in line with the scope inputs to improve the match and decrease the amplitude variation.

Comment: Thank you so much. since both port 1 and port 2 have 50 ohm termination and the cables 1 and 2 both have 50 ohm characteristic impedance, I suppose with the SMA Tee putting them in parallel, it's no longer impedance matched.   Is this the correct way to understand that I am getting some interference and hence the amplitudes on port 1 and 2 are different?

Comment: Well, the scope input might not be exactly 50 ohms. It could be slightly capacitive or inductive. This will create standing waves and therefore amplitude variation. Try adding a couple of 10 dB or 20 dB attenuators and see what happens.

Comment: The oscilloscope is in 50ohm mode and I am using 50 ohm characteristic impedance wires.  How does adding attenuators changes the impedance mismatch?

Comment: The attenuator may present an input impedance closer to 50 ohms than the scope input and therefore reduce the amplitude of any reflections, reducing the amplitude variations you're seeing.

Comment: ok, so this is like adding an impedance matching adaptor going from 1MOhm to 50Ohm.